# obtener el número de filas que contiene un XML en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml, variables, sql

Buen día.

Estoy trabajando con FOR XML en sql server y quisiera saber si hay forma de obtener el número de filas de una un XML, así como un LEN para un arreglo.

por ejemplo,esta es una varibale xml que contiene los resultados de una consulta en FOR XML PATH(' '):

```
SELECT @NOMBRE= (SELECT DISTINCT nombre FROM user ORDER BY nombre FOR XML PATH(''));
```

quisiera obtener la cantidad en entero de las filas que contiene esa variable XML. ¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguién alguna vez llega a tener esta situación, esta es la respuesta:

```
@NOMBRE.value('count(name)', 'int');
```

Gracias a todos y a todas por su atención.